# Add telegram bot to a group without start command

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

To add a bot to a group we can use this link:

```
https://telegram.me/[botname]?startgroup=foo
```

It shows up a dialog to select a group. But when the bot is added to the group a start command also gets added like this:

```
/start@[botname]
```

The problem is that group members will keep tapping on this start command and it will be awkward.

How to simply add a bot to a group without a clickable command link? Isn't there any other deep link?

Comment: As I know, there is no other link to do this.

Comment: You can use the messageID to delete those messages(via bot), emmediately after starting.

Comment: @tashakori bot should be either group admin, or the owner of the message to be able to delete it. it's not neither one

Comment: As Sean said there is no other way to prevent /start command. I think the only  way is left is that you should keep track of each chat and just ignore /start-s starting from the 2nd one .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just right click and `delete` that message.
that was solution for me.

Comment: I'm the developer, not the user. If it was me, the better solution would be "Add Member" button. I hope one day they give a link for just adding

Answer (score 0):

Delete and create your bot via BotFather again. Don't add any command via BotFather and they won't be shown in the menu.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

3 years old question but, I've tried use link without payload and the bot added to group without command:

```
/start@[botname]
```

The link without payload is like this:

```
https://t.me/[botname]?startgroup=
```

Comment: Tried and work on Telegram for iOS and Telegram for Mac (Mac App Store). Not working on Android and Telegram Lite (Mac App Store)

Comment: Hi, I've tried.

https://telegram.me/mybotname?startgroup=mygroupname,

or /start@mybotname within "mygroupname". Neither way get my bot added to the Telegram Group. Would you elaborate a bit more, like with an example pls?

Comment: Don't get it, you want to add your bot to a group right @xpt?
Let's do some test, copy and paste this link: https://t.me/quranappbot?startgroup= to your _**Saved Messages**_ and then send. After that, try to click the link on the message that you just sent to your _**Saved Messages**_ and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks hanism. Does it have to be that bot? I got `Method: contacts.resolveUsername
Result: {"_":"rpc_error","error_code":400,"error_message":"USERNAME_INVALID"}`. _Update_, tried my own bot and get exact same error as well. PS. I'm using Telegram web.

Comment: It can be any bot @username, I just random use my bot’s name as an example for you to test.

For web, it won’t work sorry and will give you error message like you mention above. As I stated before, it work on Telegram for iOS and Mac.

Comment: OK. I tried Telegram for Android, and it is not working for me -- clicking the link on the message I just sent to Saved Messages prompted me to select a group, I select one, and Telegram brings me to the group. No more steps prompted, and the bot is not added to the selected group.