# How to add a bot to a Telegram Group via API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to add a bot to a Telegram Group, but not via manual approach:

- [How to add a bot to a Telegram Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338101/),

but via API instead, i.e., something like this:

- [Add telegram bot to a group without start command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319657/)

which I had not been able to make it working. I've tried.

https://telegram.me/mybotname?startgroup=mygroupname,

or `/start@mybotname` within "mygroupname". Neither way get my bot added to the Telegram Group.

The reason I need to add a bot to Telegram Groups *via API* is that I have over a dozen of such Telegram Groups to add this new bot to.

Comment: Seems that the conclusion is -- _"impossible"_ -- I added them all manually.

Comment: yeah bot-api doesnt support that. 
But u can use this function in user account (not bot).

Comment: @AlenPaulVarghese, that will do as well, Would you elaborate it (using which function and how) into an answer pls?

Comment: User-account is using ur account as an instance, i dont know python-telegram-bot supports it but other third party libraries like telethon, pyrogram supports it. Its like automating ur account. 

There are method for adding users to a channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 years old question but, that's what helped me:

Use user API (not bot API) and messages.addChatUser method.
It works not only for adding users, but also bots.
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.addChatUser

For getting bot_id use [https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getMe](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7BTOKEN%7D/getMe) (use token from bot father)

Here is example of the code on python:

```html
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest

session = StringSession("")  # You should put your string session here
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)

async def run():
    await client.connect()  # This assumes you have already authenticated 

    result = await client(AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        user_id=bot_id,
        fwd_limit=43,
    ))
    print(result)  # prints the result

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Comment: I don't have Python to verify, but I'll make an exception, just to welcome you as a new contributor, with my +25, :)